# Is it possible to add aggregation directly logstash elasticsearch input plugin or use aggregation_fields filter for aggregation in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Could you please assist me on how I can use logstash elasticsearch input plugin to fetch aggregate data as shown in below query ? Do I need to use aggregation_fields filter {as shown below} , post querying the data from elasticsearch input plugin? Or I can add aggregation directly under input plugin.

Thanks in advance!

```
 "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "event.category": "authentication"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "event.outcome": "failure"
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "filter": [
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                              "gte": "now-1d"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "total_logon_per_user": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "user.name"
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

```
filter {
      elasticsearch {
        aggregation_fields => {
          "total_logon_per_user" => "user.name"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

RE: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-aggregation_fields

1. You need to put your query in a separate JSON file and specify it in 'query_template' property (do not use 'query', it does not allow to use aggregation.
2. In field 'user.name' you will get same hash object you can see in Elastic Dev tools, so you will need to extract required value(s) using mutate or other filters

BTW: Do not use square bracket in 'aggregation_fields', it silently breaks getting aggregation results.